# Unable execute .exe file on remote windows like psexec using python

Tags: python, windows, exe

I have found the following code(see below link) to copy and execute the commands on remote windows machine. I could able to run all the windows commands but When I give C:\file.exe as the input windows command line is not executing my command. Can I execute file in remote machine like this or is any other pythonic way of doing this? Please help...Thanks In advance

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577945-execute-remote-commands-on-windows-like-psexec/

Answer (score 0):

As with psexec, the user id being used by the script should have local administrator rights on the remote computer.  If you are using the root of C:\ to store the executable your actions could be limited by Windows security and I would also recommend using a subdirectory for the executable with the NTFS permissions relaxed (Everyone - modify) for testing.

Comment: I have added a sub directory(with permissions) but still its not executing .exe(created using py2exe). Its creating bat file with this content c:\\temp\\file.exe >> output.txt.On manually clicking on bat file my exe is getting executed  but progrmatically.Please help

Answer (score 0):

my guess would be that your py2exe executable has dependencies, and that the effective path for your executable (running remotely) is different from the path locally, and because of this, some of these dependencies are not available when run remotely.

psexec has an interactive shell option, if you use it and try to run your executable, you might get a better idea of how it is failing. you could also dump out the path and compare to the path on a local command prompt on that machine, etc.